# Getting awesome wm to work with macbook pro retina display (hidpi)

Tags: resolution, awesome-wm, macbook-pro-retina

How can I get Awesome WM to display sanely on MacBook Pro retina display?
At the moment everything is incredibly tiny..

Comment: Did you try out playing with `xrandr --dpi <dpi>`? AFAIR `awesome` uses cairo et al for rendering and those should respect RandR DPI settings.

Answer (score 3):

What's worked for me is adding `Xft.dpi: 160.0` to my .Xresources file (it's either found in `~/.Xresources`, or you can just create it there if it isn't there already), then running

```
    xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

For the interface in Awesome, if you use a theme, find the theme.lua file and define your system font to be a little less than twice the default value. You may have to adjust the size of the wiboxes in your interface (like the top menu bar), so just read through your rc.lua and adjust as necessary.

It's possible to have a great looking Awesome WM setup on Macbook Pro Retina, I promise! Mine's been working great for a few months now, and I love it.